# Is there any query to replace the NULL values with an appropriate value in this database design?

Tags: sql

I have the following database design:

```
Employee Table: EmployeeID, Name, OrgCode
Department Table: OrgCode, DepartName
CompleteSurvey Table: ID, RespondentID
```

Now, since I have some employees in the Employee Table with Null Values in the OrgCode column, I want to replace the NULL values with 'Others' value since I have 'Others' in the Department Table with the (OrgCode = 4). **So is there any query to do this for me?**

Comment: This one was quite simple, but next time, please specify the DBMS (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL) or at minimum, the language (i.e. TSQL, PLSQL).  If you don't, you'll get conflicting answers that may or may not work for you.  Additionally, you might get downvoted or worse, your question closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this query:

```
UPDATE Employee SET OrgCode = 4 WHERE OrgCode IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for ya as a one time update to a single database:

```
update employee
  set OrgCode = 4
where OrgCode is null
```

However, in other databases, 'OrgCode' may not be number 4, so here's an update that should work for all databases in your organization (or in case 'OrgCode' is not number 4).

```
update employee
  set OrgCode = d.OrgCode
from departments d
where d.DepartmentName = 'Others'
  and employee.OrgCode is null
```

Also, you might want to check the DBMS you're using to see if you can set a default value on the table's column.  This way, whenever an insert occurs and the OrgCode is missing, 'Others' will be filled in automatically.

Comment: I am not sure what dialect your SQL is, but the SQL standard does not seem to know about `UPDATE ... SET ... FROM`. What you probably wanted to write is
`UPDATE employees e SET e.orgcode = ( SELECT d.orgcode FROM departments d WHERE d.departmentname = 'Others') WHERE e.orgcode IS NULL`.

Comment: @SzilardBarany - 'employees' is not the table name, and I'm using TSQL.  I removed the alias from employee, should be fine now.

Answer (score 0):

well engines are different, but the idea is always the same:

```
update employee set OrgCode = 'Others' where OrgCode IS NULL
```

Comment: OrgCode is an integer field, not varchar.

Comment: well please give the engine then

Comment: The OP specified that the OrgCode for 'Others' is 4 in the question.  But yes, the OP should include the DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
UPDATE employee
SET    orgcode = NVL( orgcode, 4 );
```

Comment: Why update ALL records in the table when a WHERE clause is more efficient?  There could be millions of rows.

Comment: In Oracle (and I guess in other databases as well) `NULL` values are not indexed, so it will be full table scan, anyhow, not index-based access. Furthermore, unless the original poster works for Walmart, McDonald's or one of the Chinese or Indian giant companies, the number of rows in the `EMPLOYEE` table cannot be millions. A few ten thousand rows is not any considerable amount for any modern RDBMS. Finally, the average row length in the table is not huge, so most likely most data blocks will be impacted by UPDATE in any case. So, not much (if any) I/O is saved by the `WHERE`...